# How to collect years from an utterance in Dialogflow ES?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-speech-to-text-api

What is the best way to collect years from a user's utterance?
There is no specific system entity to capture years, my best guest is `@sys.date` or `@sys.number-integer`.
`@sys.date` seems to need a full date and `@sys.number-integer` works but misses when users say just "22" (need post-processing script to convert it to 2022).

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm using this on voice, so using system entities will help with the bias

Answer (score 1):

You may try and consider this alternative approach.

For you to capture uttered words and then convert it to `year` like your example **"22"** or when uttered it is **"twenty-two"** or **"two two"**, you may create a custom entity that has all the synonyms for year **2022** like the example shown below.
[image]

And when words are uttered and captured the words listed in the sysnonyms, it will return your desired year similar to below example.

[image]

For a faster way to ingest your **custom year entity**, you may create a CSV file and import it to Dialogflow. You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-export) for more details.

Comment: in that case, I will need to create a huge number of entries in custom entities and add a new entry every new year 

Comment: @PSA that is the downside of this approach since you will need to bulk ingest synonyms of a certain range of years (eg. 1900-2099). I can't seem to find any alternative except the one you mentioned where you will be needing a post-processing script. Just an additional option that you might consider in case there are other better ideas from the community